# Implement a generic class where the definition is on a base interface type but the implementation is on an interface derived from that base?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

Is it possible in C# to implement a generic class where the definition is on a base interface type but the implementation is on an interface derived from that base?

I have a base type with core functionality but I need two different variations on that type depending on if my process is working with data data or integer data.

I could kluge my base type to have both data types but I'd rather not.

Example of the problem:

```
public interface IA {}

public interface IB : IA {}

public class CA : IA {}

public class CB : IB {}

public interface IC<T1> where T1 : IA { }

public class C<TIa> : IC<TIa> where TIa : IA {}

public class Thing
{
    public void Some()
    {
        IA a = new CB(); // fine IB is of type IA
        C<IB> b = new C<IB>(); // fine - obviously

        C<IB> y = new C<IA>(); // shouldn't work - doesn't work
        C<IA> x = new C<IB>(); // even though IB is of type IA this is not acceptable
    }
}

Cannot implicitly convert type 'ClassLibrary1.C<ClassLibrary1.IA>' to     
'ClassLibrary1.C<ClassLibrary1.IB>' // this makes sense

Cannot implicitly convert type 'ClassLibrary1.C<ClassLibrary1.IB>' to 
'ClassLibrary1.C<ClassLibrary1.IA>'  // this should work - IB derives from IA
```

If I can't implement a generic on derived interfaces then I have a lot of reworking to do on an existing application.  Is there some kind of simple way to implement this?

Comment: You should tell us what actual problem you're trying to solve with this.  We might be able to come up with a simpler solution.

Comment: Maybe take a look at covariance and contravariance in interface generics? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx

Comment: I don't know how C# handles this, but in Java you could write: `C<? extends IA> x = new C<IB>();`. This makes me think that this is possible in C# as well, but probably with a different syntax :)

Comment: The root of @RobertHarvey 's question is whether generics are useful at all. It might be better to just operate on objects typed as the interface `IA`

Comment: I did tell you the actual problem.  I needed a generic type to accept different sub-types based on a common base interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you declare the type parameter `T1` of the interface `IC` as covariant

```
public interface IC<out T1> where T1 : IA { }
```

then you can assign an instance of `C<IB>` to a variable of type `IC<IA>`

```
IC<IA> x = new C<IB>(); // works
```

But I'm not sure if that answers your question...